# Liferay Smart Card CAC Authentication With Liferay 6.1

Tags: java, liferay, smartcard, cac, liferay-hook

we are building a website using Liferay and we need to Implement CAC authentication. I put in a ticket with Liferay customer support, but they would not offer a path forward, because they do not "officially" support this feature. Can anyone please tell me the best way to go about doing this?

The best resource I've found so far is a blog, at the following url talking about building a custom hook. Unfortunately, they do not give very much information on how to build and implement it.

http://www.zylk.net/es/web/guest/web-2-0/blog/-/blogs/autenticacion-en-liferay-portal-via-smart-card-tipo-dnie#_33_messageScroll208213

Thanks for your time and any assistance you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't help with the hook.

Afaik smart cards are supported by LDAP. So you could setup active directory like this:
[LDAP with AD in Liferay](https://www.liferay.com/de/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/LDAP+with+AD+in+Liferay+6.0.5)